# Any alternative for converting a number to a string?

Tags: c++

I have been trying to convert a number to a string. But the only problem is, I cannot use C++11. I know their exists functions such as `to_string` and `sstream` but all of them require C++11. Is their any other way I can do it?

Comment: `std::stringstream` doesn't require c++11.

Comment: Doesn't the usage of `<<` requires C++11?

Comment: No it doesn't require c++11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) from the C standard library:

```
#include <cstdio>
...
int i = 42;
char buffer[12]; // large enough buffer
sprintf(buffer, "%d", i);
string str(buffer);
```

Comment: http://ideone.com/4rgJSP. I don't know why but it says that `itoa` is out of scope here.

Comment: @JohnLui Oops, my mistake, `itoa` is actually non-standard in C++ and only supported by some compilers, use `sprintf` instead.

Answer (score 2):

It is conversation a number to a string in *C++03*. String streams helpful for it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>  //include this to use string streams

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number = 1234;
    double dnum = 12.789;

    ostringstream ostr1,ostr2; //output string stream
    ostr1 << number; //use the string stream just like cout,
    //except the stream prints not to stdout but to a string.

    string theNumberString = ostr1.str(); //the str() function of the stream
    //returns the string.

    //now  theNumberString is "1234"

    cout << theNumberString << endl;

    // string streams also can convert floating-point numbers to string
    ostr2 << dnum;
    theNumberString = ostr2.str();
    cout << theNumberString << endl;

    //now  theNumberString is "12.789"

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to add number to string?

```
int a = 10;
string s = a + "";
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Can it compile? If yes, then, what is the result?

Comment: It compiles, but it doesn't do the right thing. Concatenation with `+` is not supported on C-strings (`""` is a C-string). Instead it decays the `""` to a pointer of type `const char*`, and then does pointer arithmetic on that pointer, offsetting it by `a * sizeof(char)`, so the pointer points outside the C-string, thus resulting in undefined behavior.